# Are "does 'x' meet these criteria" questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Prompted by [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/85/1), should we allow questions that lay out a set of requirements and then ask if a specific piece of hardware fits them?

Answer (score 2):

I interpreted that question as, "Recommend hardware.  And, BTW, here's something I found during my research that might be suitable."  Which presumably is the kind of "show your work so far" question we want to encourage.

Even if it were literally, "Does *x* meet this need?" the [first answer to that example](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/113/84) shows that a very helpful answer can be provided even by someone who doesn't own the device.

The only time I would vote to close is if it were a question asking something that can clearly be found in published (online) specs, without any special technical knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would intuitively say that yes we should as it's directly asking if other people would recommend it.

However, I think these points need to be taken into account:

- These questions may be a bit harder to answer. In order to do answer it properly, one pretty much has to own the product (or maybe it's cousin in the same portfolio - version 2 etc.).
- Do we want to consider answers that don't specifically answer with ownership knowledge as being good? In other words `Yes, that UPS should be good because of its 600VA`  etc.

Comment: I was originally against this, but your answer actually makes a lot of sense. Now I'm not sure ahgatg to think on this.